# Obtaining 100% pure metal

Tags: metallurgy

While reading my book everywhere I found that 99.9% pure metal is obtained. Is it possible by any process that we get 100% pure metal on industrial level?

Comment: _Nothing_ is 100% pure.

Comment: 99.9% pure **is** 100% pure within certain tolerance. What tolerance do you want?

Comment: Typical industrial silicon wafers for the fabrication of integrated circuits are 99.9999999 % pure.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2870/what-is-a-pure-substance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to get a "100% pure" sample of an element is by mass spectroscopy, or something similar, which acts on each atom (or ion, actually) one at a time.

So you *could* get a [sample of pure rubidium of a few dozen atoms](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/rubbec.html). *Caveat:* "100 % pure" applies only to those atoms actually observed... there could be other elements in the vicinity that have not been observed.

Practically, though, there is no way to prevent a single atom of hydrogen, for example, from eventually contaminating your "100 %" pure sample.

Comment: True and false. There is no absolute vacuum, so any cluster would absorb some gas on their surface sooner or later even inside the ms chamber

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote.

Answer (score 6):

When we start talking about **Fineness** of metals we can deal with some misunderstanding. We generally have to make a distinction between **absolute purity** and the **common metals basis purity**. The first refers to all the impurities (all the elements of the periodic table) the second refers  only to metals. On industrial level is not possible to reach 100% absolute purity, because this means that the whole process must be carried on in ultra-clean ultra-vacuum environment. We can however reach very high purity. Usually the purity is measured in *Nines* below you can find a table that summarize the purity grades:

\begin{array}{lllll}
Nines & Purity \%  & Total Parts & Matrix  \space ppm & Impurity \space ppm \\
1N    & 90\%       & 1,000,000   & 900,000    & 100,000      \\
2N    & 99\%       & 1,000,000   & 990,000    & 10,000       \\
3N    & 99.9\%     & 1,000,000   & 999,000    & 1,000        \\
4N    & 99.99\%    & 1,000,000   & 999,900    & 100          \\
5N    & 99.999\%   & 1,000,000   & 999,990    & 10           \\
6N    & 99.9999\%  & 1,000,000   & 999,999    & 1            \\
7N    & 99.99999\% & 1,000,000   & 999,999.9  & 0.1          \\
-     & 100\%      & 1,000,000   & 1,000,000  & 0           
\end{array}

In the past Royal Canadian Mint used to mint a 5 nines gold coin and that was something very unusual, the purest gold ever produced was 999.999—six nines gold that was claimed to be refined by the Perth Mint in 1957. At sigma aldrich you can buy 99.999% trace metals basis so is not the absolute purity. If you are interest in the topic this article could be helpful [Schulze, K.K. JOM (1981) 33: 33. doi:10.1007/BF03354422](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03354422#Abs1) while a general discussion can be found [here](https://www.ameslab.gov/mpc/purityFAQ).